# Python:Extracting dates from a string and put into a list

Tags: python, string, datetime, split

I have a string like this:

```
   old_ActNacd_2016-12-21_07-09-08.txt:100:2016-12-21 07:08:20 - [HSM   ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
   old_ActNacd_2016-12-21_08-21-04.txt:52:2016-12-21 07:21:42 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
   old_ActNacd_2016-12-21_08-37-50.txt:49:2016-12-21 08:23:34 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
   old_ActNacd_2016-12-21_15-00-47.txt:49:2016-12-21 08:39:16 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
```

I tried doing like this:

```
  #creating list after taking the string out
  log_list = ostring.split('Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s')
    for itr in log_list:
        #getting the dates from the log_list
        match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', itr)
        if match:
            date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

This process works fine, but i want to do only in one operation, rather than doing in two steps(splitting and matching)

```
  Note:-I want to create a list of dates from the string present between ":" and "space" in the string. I don't want the date present with "_ActNacd_" string.
```

So i will create a list which will contain dates:

```
['2016-12-21','2016-12-21', '2016-12-21', '2016-12-21']
```

Comment: You can write regular expression to match only dates between ":" and "space" without splitting.

Answer (score 1):

With [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), you can achieve that like below:

```
re.findall(r'(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})', s)
```

If you want only the second date in each line, try:

```
re.findall(r':(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})', s)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = '''old_ActNacd_2016-12-21_07-09-08.txt:100:2016-12-21 07:08:20 - [HSM   ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
... old_ActNacd_2016-12-21_08-21-04.txt:52:2016-12-21 07:21:42 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s'''
>>>
>>> re.findall(r':(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})', s)
['2016-12-21', '2016-12-21']
```

Comment: i think it will have duplicate entries for each date, since each date is represented twice in a line for the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split by \n first, then you can iterate by line and with a reverse substring get the date and with .append() function get the desired list